# Como funciona a geolocalização de um dispositivo?

Tags: geolocalização

Andei pesquisando sobre as formas de geolocalizar um dispositivo e encontrei, de forma resumida, esses 4 tipos:

> 1. O GPS é o meio mais preciso de se determinar o posicionamento, mas ele é mesmo eficaz em termos de energia que outras opções e, às vezes, requer um tempo de inicialização longo.
> 2. O A-GPS (GPS assistencial) usa triangulação entre torres de telefones celulares e postes públicos para determinar a localização. Embora não seja tão preciso quanto o GPS, o GPS-A é suficiente para muitos cenários.
> 3. Dispositivos móveis que suportam hotspots Wi-Fi podem usar pontos de acesso para determinar a localização do usuário.
> 4. Computadores estacionários sem dispositivos sem fio podem obter informações aproximadas de localização usando faixas de endereços IP conhecidos.

O GPS, A-GPS e o IP eu entendo todo o processo. Mas quando tento entender a geolocalização através da Wi-fi, não fica claro pra mim, após ele processar o meu sinal de rede local, o que ele faz em seguida: envia dados por GPS? Ou o sistema infere o posicionamento pelo IP? Utiliza o A-GPS?

Olhando a API de Geolocalização da W3C, consigo saber os dados recebidos, mas não sei como ele capta (todos os notebooks e smartphones, possuem um hardware dedicado a isso) essas informações.

Answer (score 7):

Para ajudar a fazer uma localização mais precisa ainda é que entra o Wi-Fi!! Quando os carros da Google partiram para as ruas para fazer as capturas de imagens para o [Street View](https://www.instantstreetview.com), também passaram a capturar dados de todas as redes wireless que encontravam. Principalmente nome, *MAC Address* (é um código numérico que em tese identificaria unicamente cada equipamento) e nível do sinal. O que gerou em muitos lugares uma imensa discussão sobre invasão de privacidade. Como a esmagadora maioria dos roteadores Wi-Fi possui um sinal de curto alcance (cerca de 100 metros em condições ideais), é possível saber onde o usuário está com certa precisão caso existam vários roteadores! Basta verificar o sinal de cada um deles e fazer o processo análogo ao do A-GPS.

Dessa forma juntando o A-GPS com o Wi-Fi é possível obter uma localização inicial muito mais precisa, até que os satélites do sistema de GPS sejam encontrados. E essa informação, mesmo que imprecisa, também ajuda a localizar os satélites mais rapidamente, pois assim o aparelho sabe exatamente quais satélites estão em sua região e busca apenas por eles (consultando um banco de dados remoto).

E aqui entra mais um detalhe de como essa coleta de informações é feita. Não é apenas através dos carros do Street View, mas os próprios usuários colaboram com isso ao habilitar o GPS no seu aparelho no primeiro acesso.

Leia mais nesse artigo [Por que o Android pede pra ligar o wi-fi ao acessar o GPS?](http://spelunkeroid.aguilarj.com/por-que-o-android-pede-pra-ligar-o-wi-fi-ao-acessar-o-gps/)

Comment: `O que gerou em muitos lugares uma imensa discussão sobre invasão de privacidade` Não fico surpreso. Mas pra mim é mais um problema de RTFM do que de privacidade. Todo roteador tem uma opção pra não fazer broadcast do SSID da rede. BTW +1.

Comment: @Renan concordo contigo, ninguem é forçado a usar, mas é mania da maioria das pessoas não lê os termos e sair concordando, e depois reclamar aos 7 ventos que empresa X vigia sua privacidade. Ora, se não concorda, porque aceitou? Infelizmente a escolha é entre usar ou não usar, ai vai de cada um pesar isso para si.